# Cutting a parabola

Tags: conic-sections

What would be obtained on cutting the solid parabola. I searched various sites,most of them say cone. But I am unable to visualize it. Can Someone please help.

Comment: What is a "solid parabola"? Do you mean a [paraboloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Paraboloid_of_Revolution.svg)?

Comment: @devender Slant cutting a paraboloid of revolution surface produces an ellipse. If cutting plane is along or perpendicular to axis  intersection curve is a parabola or circle respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You get a parabola by intersecting a plane with a cone, not viceversa.
[image]

Comment: Are you Sure that its not vice- versa ?

Comment: Parabolas and related curves are called *conic sections* because they are the intersection of a cone and a plane... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_Section

Comment: @devender Yes, I can't find a way to get a 3d shape by cutting a 2d one